# How can i use same object in different classes in Java

Tags: java

Suppose i have 3 java classes A , B and C

I need to create an object of class C that is used in both A and B but the problem in creating the object separately is that the constructor of class c is called 2 times. But i want the constructor to be called just once.

So i want to use the object created in class A into class b.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So create the object once, and pass it into the constructors of A and B:

```
C c = new C();
A a = new A(c);
B b = new B(c);

...

public class A 
{
    private final C c;

    public A(C c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Note that this is *very* common in Java as a form of *dependency injection* such that objects are told about their collaborators rather than constructing them themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Create object C outside of both A and B and have the constructors of A and B accept an instance of class C.

```
class A {
   public A( C c ) {
       ....
   }
}

class B {
   public B( C c ) {
       ....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if the constructors for A and B are not called near each other you could define Class c as a singleton.  See http://mindprod.com/jgloss/singleton.html

you would then do:

```
A a = new A(C.getInstance());
B b = new B(C.getInstance());
```

or alternatively, in constructors for `A` and `B` just call getInstance instead of the constructor, ie.

```
// C c = new C();
C c = C.getInstance();
```

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet that the DI style of adding C as a constructor parameter is a common (and useful) design pattern in Java

Answer (score 0):

You want to share an instance? Ok, how about his:

```
C c = new C();
B b = new B(c);
A a = new A(c);
```

Another option is:

```
B b = new B();
A a = new A(b.c);
```