# Call a method of the object which is created in another class

Tags: java, object, reference

I have a little problem.

I have a 3 classes looks "like" this:

```
public class Gun{
    public void Shot(){
        // shoot code
    }

    public void RenderGun()
    {
        // render code
    }

    // more methods
}


public class GameManager
{
    Gun gun;

    public GameManager()
    {
        gun = new Gun();
    }

    // methods using GunClass methods.
}

public class HudScreen
{
    Gun gun;

    public HudScreen()
    {
        gun = new Gun();
    }

    public void GunShotButton()
    {
        gun.Shoot();
    }
}
```

The problem is I have two Gun objects and i want to have one but use it in both classes HudScreen and GameManager.

So, if I create a new Gun object in GameManager, how to "call" this object from the HudScreen class?

---

Thanks, MM.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088221/accessing-objects-of-other-classes or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762283/how-can-i-use-same-object-in-different-classes-in-java

Comment: If you want to have only one gun object, you can make `static final` Gun object in GameManager class and you must initialize it in a static block. you can reach it from Hudscreen class: `GameManager.gun`

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret i'll check this

Comment: @mustafacil i dont want to create only one gun object but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameManager constructor

```
 public GameManager(Gun gun){ 
     this.gun = gun;
 }
```

HudScreen constructor

```
public HudScreen(Gun gun){
      this.gun = gun;
 }
```

From the main method where you create the Gun object you can pass it to the constructors of GameManager and HudScreen

```
 public static void main() {
      Gun gun = new Gun();
      HudScreen hudScreen = new HudScreen(gun);
      GameManager gameManager = new GameManager(gun)
   }
```

If you do not want to create GameManager and HudScreen in same method but still want to use same Gun object then you can do it this way 
1. Initialize Gun object
2. on the GameManager and Hudscreen you can either pass it on constructor or you can directly pass it to method in theses classes.
e.g. Assume you want to keep the GameManager constructor receive the newly created Gun and pass the same gun to Hudscreen.GunShotButton. I hope you got a clue here -

```
public class Gun{
    public void Shot(){
        // shoot code
    }

    public void RenderGun()
    {
        // render code
    }

    // more methods
}


public class GameManager
{
    Gun gun;

    public GameManager(Gun gun)
    {
        this.gun =gun;
    }

    // methods using GunClass methods.
}

public class HudScreen
{   
    public HudScreen()
    {
    }

    public void GunShotButton(Gun gun)
    {
        gun.Shoot();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but what if i won't create HudScreen and GameManager objects in the same method like main?

I want to create HudScreen and GameManager objects in two different classes(objects). 

It's still possible to get to both of them the same Harpoon object?

Comment: About your edit:

Truly... you are very helpful but i still dont know where to initlialize gun object.

Comment: Okay. I get it now. Anyway I have made a few mistakes and now I'm going to rework my Game Engine. 

Thanks, you are great. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Change constructors in that way:

```
public GameManager(Gun gun) {
   this.gun = gun;
}
```

and the same in `HudScreen` class.
Then in some Main class:

```
class Main {    
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Gun gun = new Gun();
      HudScreen hudScreen = new HudScreen(gun);
      GameManager gameManager = new GameManager(gun)
   }
}
```

Currently `main` method is assumed to be the top level method doing the initilization. This may be some other method as well where objects of `Gun` , `GunManager` and `HudScreen` are created.

Answer (score -1):

register a ScreenController to every NiftyGUI screen.  create a ScreenController by creating a Java class that implements the de.lessvoid.nifty.screen.ScreenController interface and its abstract methods.

Comment: The question is generic and does not talk about nifty at all. A generic java solution is better than imposing the specifications of a specific library or framework for such question.